# get all classess, sub classess from owl in java

Tags: java, semantics, rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I have ontology file. owl
from that i need to get all classes, subclasses from owl

```
File file = new File("myontology.owl");

OWLOntology myontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + myontology);

// We can always obtain the location where an ontology was loaded from
IRI documentIRI = manager.getOntologyDocumentIRI(myontology);

OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLClass clsOwl = factory.getOWLClass(documentIRI);
```

then what should i write? i checked OWLAPI, but i am very new on semantic. In order to get ,

like following example, using owl2api i need a code ,

```
String uri = "http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/travel/travel.owl";

OWLModel owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(uri);

Collection classes = owlModel.getUserDefinedOWLNamedClasses();
for (Iterator it = classes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

    OWLNamedClass cls = (OWLNamedClass) it.next();
    Collection instances = cls.getInstances(false);
    System.out.println("Class " + cls.getBrowserText() + " (" + instances.size() + ")");

    for (Iterator jt = instances.iterator(); jt.hasNext();) {
        OWLIndividual individual = (OWLIndividual) jt.next();
        System.out.println(" - " + individual.getBrowserText());
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: so what exactly doesn't work now? It looks for me that OwlModel.getUserDefinedOWLNamedClasses() returns all user defined classes. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that's what you need, but

```
OwlOntology.getClassesInSignature()
```

returns the set of all classes that are used to build axioms in the current ontology.

Also once you have OwlClass you can get it's subclasses using

```
 OwlClass.getSubClasses(OWLOntology)
```